# Get global module variable in vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript

So i have below module created according to an example i found.

I initialize it with

```
equipment_booking = new equipment({
    equipment: '#equipment_order',
    type: '#equipment_type_order',
    validation: '#equipment_validation_order',
    submit: "#submit_booking"
});
```

What I want to do is access the `typeVar` from outside the module. I found out that I need to use the `this.` in front of it. And indeed I could access it. However I can't seem to access it inside the module functions. How would I accomplish this? This is a part of the module I have written. I have tried different ways in the checkInput function. Any help or suggestions are realy appriciated.

```
var equipment = (function() {
    function equipment(options) {
        // Set the standard options
        var o = {
            equipment: null,
            type: null,
            validation: null,
            submit: null
        };

        // Get some other needed variables
        number = "";
        this.typeVar = 0;
        var error = [{
            code: 0,
            msg: ""
        }];

        // Then we can override the given options to the standard options
        for (var k in options) {
            if (options.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
                o[k] = document.querySelector(options[k]);
            }
        }

        // Add the eventlisteners
        o.equipment.addEventListener('keydown', checkInput);
        o.equipment.addEventListener('blur', validateInput);
        o.type.addEventListener('change', validateInput);

        function checkInput(e) {
            console.log("CheckInput called"); // This console.log is called
            console.log(typeVar);             // Error: typeVar is not defined
            console.log(this.typeVar);        // Undefined
            e.preventDefault();               // The e works
        }

        function validateInput() {
            // Validating input
        }
    }
    return equipment;
})();
```

Comment: What is "_global module variable_"?

Comment: because the function is bound to the input. You either have to use fat arrow or bind()

Comment: change the function declaration for `checkInput()` to `checkInput = (e)=> {...}` and the `this` keyword will work. Read about why [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#arrow_functions_used_as_methods).

Comment: @RandyCasburn When i change to your suggestion, i can't do the checkInput on the eventlistener. How should i call it then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are using some very old vanilla js. I suppose it is to support old browsers. Let's keep that support using a simple technique that it's called "saving `this` in a helper variable `self`"

```
    function equipment(options) {
        // Set the standard options
        var o = {
            equipment: null,
            type: null,
            validation: null,
            submit: null
        };

        // Get some other needed variables
        number = "";
        this.typeVar = 0;
        var error = [{
            code: 0,
            msg: ""
        }];

        // Then we can override the given options to the standard options
        for (var k in options) {
            if (options.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
                o[k] = document.querySelector(options[k]);
            }
        }

        // Add the eventlisteners
        o.equipment.addEventListener('keydown', checkInput);
        o.equipment.addEventListener('blur', validateInput);
        o.type.addEventListener('change', validateInput);

        var self = this;
        function checkInput(e) {
            console.log("CheckInput called"); // This console.log is called
            console.log(typeVar);             // Error: typeVar is not defined
            console.log(this.typeVar);        // Undefined
            console.log(self.typeVar);        // Defined
            e.preventDefault();               // The e works
        }

        function validateInput() {
            // Validating input
        }
    }
    return equipment;
})();
```

The reason this works is because when the interpreter creates a new function such as `checkInput`, it sees all the variables that are around and puts them inside a "backpack". This backpack of variables is available when you execute the function later. Now you may ask: "Why is `this` not referencing my equipment class? Why is not in the backpack?". Thats because `this` in that callback is referencing other thing from the event callback. It got "replaced" inside that callback. Thats why you don't have it.

Edit:

A more modern approach would be to [use class syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) without changing too much the code, and for the callbacks, we would use class properties as arrow functions which hold the correct `this` class context when the event listeners call them.

Please, take a careful look at the name "Equipment", now it has a capital "E". The class instantiation should be `new Equipment()` now.
More info on https://devopedia.org/naming-conventions

```
class Equipment {
    constructor(options) {
        // Set the standard options
        const o = {
            equipment: null,
            type: null,
            validation: null,
            submit: null
        };

        // Get some other needed variables
        let number = "";
        this.typeVar = 0;
        const error = [{
            code: 0,
            msg: ""
        }];

        // Then we can override the given options to the standard options
        for (let k in options) {
            if (options.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
                o[k] = document.querySelector(options[k]);
            }
        }

        // Add the event-listeners
        o.equipment.addEventListener('keydown', this.checkInput);
        o.equipment.addEventListener('blur', this.validateInput);
        o.type.addEventListener('change', this.validateInput);
    }

    checkInput = (e) => {
        console.log("CheckInput called"); // This console.log is called
        console.log(this.typeVar);        // defined
        e.preventDefault();               // The e works
    }

    validateInput = () => {
        // Validating input
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this works. However you comment that this is an old way to support old browsers. I don't need to support old browsers. I'm just not that experienced in this. So if you know of a better way, please feel free to show me the newer way

Comment: Sure thing. Here you go. You can test the new syntax here https://codepen.io/tomas2387/pen/Yzrrvod?editors=1111

Comment: Thanks a lot. You have helped me a great deal. i have accepted your awnser